# unnecessary <html> element added when th:replace

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I am using `th:replace` to include templates in Thymeleaf like this

master.html

```
<div class="faq-wrapper">
    <div th:each="faq : ${faqs}" th:remove="tag">
        <div th:replace="content-faq-card"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

content-faq-card.html

```
<div class="faq-card">
    ...
</div>
```

I initialize my templateRenderer like this:

```
ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();

templateResolver.setTemplateMode("LEGACYHTML5");
templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
templateResolver.setCacheable(false);

TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

return templateEngine;
```

It works fine, but if I look into generated HTML I see that everytime I include `content-faq-card` there is extra

```
<HTML><head></head><BODY>
<div class="faq-card">
    ...
</div>
</BODY></HTML>
```

It renders correctly, but HTML is not valid. Why does this wrapping happen? Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: I think you need to define your <div class="faq-card"> as <div th:fragment="faq-card">, and reference it as <div th:replace="content-faq-card :: faq-card"></div>.

Comment: What Tashci says. Here is a link to the related documentation: [defining and referencing fragments](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#defining-and-referencing-fragments).

Comment: @Taschi: thank you, it helped :) ... feel free to post as an answer, I will accept it, so it can help other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your `<div class="faq-card">` as `<div th:fragment="faq-card">`, and reference it as `<div th:replace="content-faq-card :: faq-card"></div>`.